# Can not allocate vector - lapply function

Tags: r

With this function I subtract each column from the entire df. Now the df is too big and I got always the error message: can not allocate vector of size. Is there a possibility to split the task in different parts to get the same result?

Or any idea what I can do? The df is about 2500 columns.

Thank you for any advice or help!!

```
CX <- lapply(df, function(x) df - x)
```

Update:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyverse")
library("dlookr")
library("plyr")
library("readxl")
library("qpcR")
library("ggplot2")
library("matrixStats")



ZZ <- data.frame( Date = c("05-01-2001", "05-02-2001", "05-03-2001", "05-04-2001", "05-06-2001"),
                  Paris = c(25.3, 25.4, 26, 26.1, 25.6),
                  Berlin = c(18.5, 18.1, 19, 20.1, 23.9),
                  Tokyo = c(23.6, 23.9, 26, 26.5, 27),
                  Funchal = c(33.7, 32, 32.1, 31.4, 30.5),
                  Penaforte = c(26.1, 26, 26, 26.4, 26.1))


memory.limit(9999999999999) # 

ZZ500 <- select_if(ZZ, is.numeric)

getDiff <- function(ZZ, idx) {
  
  #This is the function to calculate all the temperature diffs
  
  num.rows <- nrow(ZZ)
  
  output.range <- 1:(num.rows-1)
  
  
  
  diff1  <- ZZ[output.range,1:ncol(ZZ)]
  diff2 <- ZZ[output.range+idx,1:ncol(ZZ)]
  
  diff3 <- data.frame(((diff1) / (diff2) -1))
  
  
  
  return(diff3)
  
}

out <- lapply(1:4, function(x) getDiff(ZZ500, x)) # calculates all diffs over a several period (here 1 to 4 days)

All_Diffs <- as.data.frame(out) 

All_Diffs_V1 <- All_Diffs

for(i in 1:ncol(All_Diffs_V1)){ #Negative changes = 0, Positive changes = 1
  
  All_Diffs_V1[ ,i] <- ifelse (All_Diffs_V1[ ,i] > 0,  1, 0)
  
}

df <- All_Diffs_V1

result <- lapply(df, function(x) df - x) # Subtract all the columns, possible results: 1,0,-1
result.df <- data.frame(result)
```

The last part is not included. In this part I try to find out as an example: how many times in each 16th of may for every year the temperature between Paris and Tokyo was negative or positive and that for each column pair, each day and for every time period.

Comment: Can I ask what you want to do with the final result?

Comment: And how many rows does it have?

Comment: It has 3181rows. It's just intermediary step for further processing. After this I have 2500^2 column pairs, which I try to compare with each other.

Comment: This code seems to create 2500 copies of the original data frame (with some modification).  This is huge. You perhaps cannot hold the resulted objects in memory.  The question is if you really need that in the memory or you can achieve your goal by writing each object to the disk.

Comment: How can I do this "to write each object to the disk" ?

Comment: `2500^2*5874` reals (C language double) times 8 bytes each is 2.9e+11 bytes or 273.5 GB. Shouldn't you revise the problem or, [also possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), the solution?

Comment: I think if you described a bit more widely what this step is needed for and what you want to achieve as the ultimate goal, there is likely a different solution available.

Comment: OK, now it only has 3181 rows or 148.1 GB. Still big.

Comment: All these data are about temperature. I want to calculate from each column the difference in the temperature and after this I try to explore for each date if the temperature is positive or negative.

Comment: so, each row is a date and each column the temperature at a certain place?

Comment: yes, exactly! 2500 places.

Comment: ok, and then you want to compare if the temperature in these 2499 places is higher compared to your reference place `x` for each date/row. Once you have this, what do you do with this?

Comment: But I think (and I don't know how to do this) we can reduce it because if I subtract column 1 from column 2 there is no need to do this the other way around (Column two from column 1). If we are able to manage this, the amount of columns would be (2500^2) / 2

Comment: Yes, but each column is a reference place, because I want to subtract column 1 from each column, then column 2 from each column and so on. I will search for the 2000 biggest and most frequent changes. So I will pick a date let's say 11 of December and compare every 11th of December from each year 1998 -2020 and look for each place the temperature difference is positive or negative (the frequency). If you want we can mail each other, it's maybe a bit easier.

Comment: email would be: selinawalter05@gmail.com

Comment: Could you create a sample data frame with say 4 columns and 5 rows and show us your code for the end to end processing? You will likely have to iterate for one column at a time to avoid the memory strain.

Comment: I've added the code and some example data, if you have any question, just ask! Hopefully it is easy to read the code. Thank you for your help!